# Row.key and row.value not working in spark structure streaming code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro

My below code is giving error row.key and row.value while reading AVRO
format from producer in spark structure streaming. please help in
resolving issue. I am getting error as row.key symbol and row.value
not found. I want to read data in Spark and write it to cassandra in hadoop 
system.I see this is the only way to read AVRO source data in spark structure streaming. Please let me know if there is any other way to read kafka data from producer in AVRO format.

```
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSource.Timestamp
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._


object ReadKafkaAvro {

  case class DeserializedFromKafkaRecord(key: String, value: String)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {



    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("ReadKafkaAvro")
      .config("spark.master", "local")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

      val schemaRegistryURL = "http://vtorppsdv01.corp.moneris.com:8081"
      val topics = "b24_tx_financial_formatted_clean"
      val subjectValueName = topics + "-value"

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    val restService = new RestService(schemaRegistryURL)

    val valueRestResponseSchema = restService.getLatestVersion(subjectValueName)

    //Use Avro parsing classes to get Avro Schema
    val parser = new Schema.Parser
    val topicValueAvroSchema: Schema = parser.parse(valueRestResponseSchema.getSchema)

    //key schema is typically just string but you can do the same process for the key as the value
    val keySchemaString = "\"string\""
    val keySchema = parser.parse(keySchemaString)



    //Create a map with the Schema registry url.
    //This is the only Required configuration for Confluent's KafkaAvroDeserializer.
    val props = Map("schema.registry.url" -> schemaRegistryURL)
    val client = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryURL, 20)

    //Declare SerDe vars before using Spark structured streaming map. Avoids non serializable class exception.
    var keyDeserializer: KafkaAvroDeserializer = null
    var valueDeserializer: KafkaAvroDeserializer = null

    //Create structured streaming DF to read from the topic.
    val rawTopicMessageDF = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "vtorppsdv01.corp.moneris.com:9093,vtorppsdv02.corp.moneris.com:9093,vtorppsdv03.corp.moneris.com:9093")
      .option("subscribe", topics)
       .option("specific.avro.reader", "true")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .option("group_id","b24_ptlf_eim_processing")
      .option("security.protocol","SSL")
      .option("ssl.keystore.location","C:\\Users\\pawan.likhi\\Desktop\\spark code\\SimpleKafkaConsumer\\kafka-eim-dev.jks")
      .option("ssl.keystore.password","BW^1=|sY$j")
      .option("ssl.key.password","BW^1=|sY$j")
      .option("ssl.truststore.location","C:\\Users\\pawan.likhi\\Desktop\\spark code\\SimpleKafkaConsumer\\cpbp-ca-dev.jks")
      .option("ssl.truststore.password","iB>3v$6m@9")//remove for prod
      .load()



    //instantiate the SerDe classes if not already, then deserialize!
    val deserializedTopicMessageDS = rawTopicMessageDF.map{
      row =>
        if (keyDeserializer == null) {
          keyDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer
          keyDeserializer.configure(props.asJava, true)  //isKey = true
        }
        if (valueDeserializer == null) {
          valueDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer
          valueDeserializer.configure(props.asJava, false) //isKey = false
        }

        //Pass the Avro schema.
        val deserializedKeyString = keyDeserializer.deserialize(topics, row.key, keySchema).toString //topic name is actually unused in the source code, just required by the signature. Weird right?
      val deserializedValueJsonString = valueDeserializer.deserialize(topics, row.value, topicValueAvroSchema).toString

        DeserializedFromKafkaRecord(deserializedKeyString, deserializedValueJsonString)
    }

    val deserializedDSOutputStream = deserializedTopicMessageDS.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", false)
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()

  }
}
```

Comment: See this? https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS

Comment: Also if you're loading data from Kafka to Cassandra or HDFS, Confluent generally recommends using Kafka Connect. And Landoop has a Cassandra loader, I believe

Comment: I found its not easy to read kafka AVRO format data. I developed code in spark streaming using twitter bijection but I am getting invert byte error any suggestion.

Comment: Error : Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): com.twitter.bijection.InversionFailure: Failed to invert: [B@5335860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found its not easy to read kafka AVRO format data. I developed code in spark streaming using twitter bijection but I am getting invert byte error any suggestion.

```
Error : Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): com.twitter.bijection.InversionFailure: Failed to invert: [B@5335860
```

New Code I used:

```
import com.twitter.bijection.Injection
import com.twitter.bijection.avro.GenericAvroCodecs
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.{CachedSchemaRegistryClient, SchemaRegistryClient}
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.{KafkaAvroDecoder, KafkaAvroDeserializer}
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.{ByteArrayDeserializer, StringDeserializer}
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.hadoop.io.AvroDeserializer
import org.apache.commons.codec.StringDecoder


object ReadKafkaAvro1 {

   object Injection {

  val schemaRegistryURL = "http://vtorppsdv01.corp.moneris.com:8081"
 val topics = "b24_tx_financial_formatted_clean"
   val subjectValueName = topics + "-value"
    val restService = new RestService(schemaRegistryURL)
    val valueRestResponseSchema = restService.getLatestVersion(subjectValueName)
  val parser = new Schema.Parser()
 //   val schema = parser.parse(getClass.getResourceAsStream("src\\main\\resources\\b24_tx_financial_formatted_clean.avsc"))
    val schema = parser.parse((valueRestResponseSchema.getSchema))
        val injection: Injection[GenericRecord, Array[Byte]] = GenericAvroCodecs.toBinary(schema)
 }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ReadKafkaAvro").setMaster("local[*]")
    val streamingCtx = new StreamingContext(conf,Seconds(30))
    val schemaRegistryURL1 = "http://vtorppsdv01.corp.moneris.com:8081"
    val topics = Array("b24_tx_financial_formatted_clean")

    streamingCtx.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val kafkaParms = Map[String,Object]("bootstrap.servers" -> "vtorppsdv01.corp.moneris.com:9093,vtorppsdv02.corp.moneris.com:9093,vtorppsdv03.corp.moneris.com:9093",
      "key.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
      "value.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer",
      "group.id" -> "b24_ptlf_eim_processing" ,
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
      "auto.commit.interval.ms" -> "2000",
      "schema.registry.url" -> schemaRegistryURL1,
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean),
      "security.protocol" -> "SSL",
      "ssl.keystore.location" -> "C:\\Users\\pawan.likhi\\Desktop\\spark code\\SimpleKafkaConsumer\\kafka-eim-dev.jks",
      "ssl.keystore.password" -> "BW^1=|sY$j",
      "ssl.key.password" -> "BW^1=|sY$j",
      "ssl.truststore.location" -> "C:\\Users\\pawan.likhi\\Desktop\\spark code\\SimpleKafkaConsumer\\cpbp-ca-dev.jks",
      "ssl.truststore.password" -> "iB>3v$6m@9",
      "ssl.keystore.type" -> "JCEKS",
      "ssl.truststore.type" -> "JCEKS",
      "specific.avro.reader" -> "True"
    )

    val inputStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String,Array[Byte]](streamingCtx,PreferConsistent,Subscribe[String,Array[Byte]](topics,kafkaParms))



    val recordStream = inputStream.map(msg => Injection.injection.invert(msg.value()).get)
   // .map(record => (record.get("AuthorizationTransactionSource"),record.get("AuthorizationTransactionSourceID")))



    inputStream.map(x => (x.key,x.value)).print()

    //recordStream.print()


    recordStream.print()

    streamingCtx.start()
    streamingCtx.awaitTermination()


  }
}
```

Comment: Bijection doesn't use a schema registry. With this approach, you're just re-doing the internal methods that the `KafkaAvroDeserializer` by Confluent already does. And if you get an error, this shouldn't be an accepted answer